# Typescript complaining about browser.params

Tags: typescript, protractor

**IDE** : Visual Studio Code

protractor.conf.js:

```
params: {
    test: true,
},
```

spec:

```
import {browser, element, by, $, $$} from 'protractor/globals';
class test{    
    if(browser.params.test === true){
        console.log('success');
    }
}
```

on running `npm run tsc` it gives me an error `error TS1005: ',' expected.` on IF statement.

[image]

Comment: Agree with below comment. Did you think how you are going to use this class? Based on above example I would first suggest you to read OOPs concepts. The other suggestion, try a testing framework such as Jasmine. That will give you proper way to write tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is not valid. Do you mean to run the if-block in the constructor instead?

```
import {browser, element, by, $, $$} from 'protractor/globals';
class test {
    constructor() {
        if(browser.params.test === true){
            console.log('success');
        }
    }
}
```